# Associating Contacts to Companies within Address Book

Tags: icloud, contacts

I've started using iCloud to manage my contacts. One thing I really like is the ability to have custom defined fields, and have them voice activated from my iPhone.

One problem however is this small (niche) area with regards to my company. I know that I can easily work around it, but I'm hoping for a definitive answer.

Here's the example.

Say I have 3 people who work for my company.

> Smith, Joe
> Doe, John
> Lew, Sue

My company is called `Acme Holdings Inc.` and there are two campuses.

> Acme Holdings North
> Acme Holdings South

Now I'd like to have in my address book

> Acme Holdings Inc
> --Phone--
> North Campus (555)-1234
> South Campus (555)-5678

Then I'd like to be able to voice dial one of my co-works with the following command

> *Call Joe Smith, North Campus*

---

So my question is, is there a way to associate a company with their respective contact information to each of the employees without having to do double/triple entries?

My problem is compounded with the fact that there are 20 some co-workers that work back and forth between 3 campuses. I'd like to have all of them in my address book.

---

#### EDIT

The reason the association would be nice would be because I don't want to have to enter the "Acme Holdings" contact numbers for each staff member. It's just nicer if you have an "Acme Holdings" contact card, and point all of the staff to it, and the custom "North Campus" and "South Campus" phone numbers are automagically attached to each contact.

Comment: I don't know a way to associate the contacts with company cards as you describe. Why do you want to specify a name in the voice command? It seems like you should just say "Call North Campus" or "Call South Campus".

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I created a "Acme Holdings" company and two custom fields "North Campus" and "South Campus". Then for the "people" I don't have any campus phone numbers in their contact card, just their mobile device.

Comment: I added an edit to the original question.